# Редирект на jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

В чем ошибка? В консоли **`missing : after property id go2Page();`**

```
$(document).ready(function ({
    go2Page();
});

function go2Page() {
    document.location.href = http: //likebox.ru/qr/cupon/860984434/cupon.php;
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Кто-то, кажется, скобочки забыл :D ...

$(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Синтаксическая ошибка.
У вас так:

```
$(document).ready(function({…}));
```

Когда надо так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){…});
```

Comment: точно, это я как-то не заметил

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = "http://likebox.ru/qr/cupon/860984434/cupon.php";
```

Comment: Все равно не работает:

    http://likebox.ru/qr/cupon/1901310372/index.php